# Array to Object with Values in a Range

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a crazy requirement here. I am not sure how to make it work well, may be I thought of getting the community's help here. This is the first time here for me. Let me explain my situation clearly.

I have an array of, say 10 elements.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].reverse();
```

Now I need to create an object of keys containing the array elements, but their values should be like:

- First 5 to be "high".
- Next 3 to be "medium".
- Rest 2 to be "low".

I do have the above information in another array:

```
var capacity = [5, 3, 2];
```

The above three values (`high`, `medium`, low) are static. Not sure how to proceed from here. I am not sure if I should be using a `for` loop hardcoded like:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < capacity[0]; i++)
  obj[arr[i]] = "high";
for (; i < capacity[0] + capacity[1]; i++)
  obj[arr[i]] = "medium";
for (; i < capacity[0] + capacity[1] + capacity[2]; i++)
  obj[arr[i]] = "low";
```

Not sure if this is the right way to proceed. Any pointers for the right direction? Thanks.

**Snippet**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].reverse();
var capacity = [5, 3, 2];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < capacity[0]; i++)
  obj[arr[i]] = "high";
for (; i < capacity[0] + capacity[1]; i++)
  obj[arr[i]] = "medium";
for (; i < capacity[0] + capacity[1] + capacity[2]; i++)
  obj[arr[i]] = "low";
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Why do you think you need to do something else? I mean, yes, there are probably at least half a dozen ways to solve this problem. You've found one, it works just fine, so...?

Comment: What' the exact expected result ? [5:[6,7,8,9],3:[3,4],1:[1,2]] ?

Comment: @PierreGranger: Seems clear to me from the question; see also the output of the snippet at the end.

Comment: You're right have'nt seen the snippet result sorry. Well this looks ok to me too. Probably not the best way but still works. Unless there is a really huge numbers of values to treat..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The output is good. Is there any better or is this the only good way? If so, I am happy to delete it. One thing that bothers me is I feel being repetitive in the case of `for` loop. Don't you feel that?

Comment: Sure. :-) But SO isn't for open-ended questions with multiple correct answers (there's a "Too broad" close reason for just that ... reason). It may be that after reviewing [their guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you might want to post on codereview.

Comment: 1250 numbers! Wow! @T.J.Crowder Doesn't that get a hit? I think there should be a better way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Should I post this in CR then?

Comment: @PierreGranger: Other than caching the values of `capacity[0]`, `capacity[1]`, and `capacity[2]`, why would a large number of numbers be an issue?

Comment: @Soolie: I'd review their guidelines first, but I don't think it's a fit for SO. It's always a judgement call, though. Good luck! FWIW, your solution seems just fine (other than probably worth caching those values, see my comment above, so they don't have to get looked up every iteration of the loops).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Last clarification. So caching you mean by `var high = capacity[0];` of that sort?

Comment: @Soolie: Yes. Although even that may be a micro-optimization. *If* that aspect presents a performance issue, I'd expect a modern JavaScript engine to handle optimizing it (as there are no writes to `capacity` in those loops). But if the volume is just 1,250 numbers, frankly, it's not likely to matter. (I'm a recovering premature micro-optimizer...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. What would be the best way? You kinda write a better answer (or explain the above) and I accept it or I just delete this question?

Comment: @Soolie: I'd delete the question, not because it's in any way a bad question, but because SO's format doesn't fit these sorts of questions.

Comment: I don't get your 1250 values... you mean that for 1,2 it's low, 3,4,5 it's medimu and rest of it is high that's it ? So in your 1250, assuming each value is a key in result, you will have 1250 keys, and 1245 will be "high" ?

Comment: @PierreGranger: *Excellent* question.

Comment: @PierreGranger No, there's a huge table, where I need to apply these values. That contains about 12000 values. The values I told are 1 - 10. It would be like 1 - 1250. Got it?

Comment: I guess this might be an XY Problem as defined in SO. I am using this data to do another big transformation. Well, wish me good luck. And thanks @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: Undeleting this for referring it for another question.